# How to extend the icon library with custom icons

Tags: reactjs, package, material-ui, icons

I am using icons from @material-ui/icons in my React projects and I need to extend it with a set of custom icons. I would like to provide this set as a shared package available via a private NPM repository, the same way material-ui icons are provided. What is the best approach to do this?

I found this blog post:
http://nicolasgallagher.com/making-svg-icon-libraries-for-react-apps/

The author uses scripts similar to the material-ui/icons scripts to generate .js/.d.ts from .svg, and reproduce what their build is doing. Is that the correct way?
I saw that the builder script of material-ui/icons accepts an argument for the path where the .svg are located, and it makes me wonder if I shouldn't use this somehow.
If you are building packages of icons for react apps, can you comment on how you are building them?

Best regards